# Is it possible to install Ubuntu 20.04 using something similar to Windows setup.exe?

Tags: boot, system-installation, executable

I am developing an automated system to install a certain OS, and I would like to be able to install Ubuntu by executing a command (like Setup.exe for Windows) instead of mounting a drive and rebooting. I can already boot to the installer using PXE, but PXE doesn't satisfy all my requirements.

Is there a command to initiate the OS install process on Ubuntu, or am I just out of luck?

Comment: Automated *from what starting point*? Windows? Blank computer without any OS?

Comment: From a blank VM on Hyper-v.

Comment: Now that you asked that question, I understand where my process is flawed. Back to the drawing board. Thanks though.

Comment: You can [automate installation](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall), either via PXE or mounted ISO image...

Comment: While this question might be [on-topic](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) here, it may also be more suitable to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) or [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) SE communities and you may have a better chance of finding a solution there IMO.